# связь таблиц в laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, orm, eloquent

Доброго времени суток.

Объясните, пожалуйста, преимущества связи таблиц средствами Eloquent.

В данный момент в моём проекте такая логика (модель orders):

```
function getClient():clients {
    return clients::find($this->client_id);
}
```

Таким образом (прямое обращение к модели, без "связей") я получаю объект в котором имею все методы определённые в модели `clients` и IDE может о них подсказывать.

В ORM Eloquent предлагается использовать `hasOne`, `hasMany` и пр. , используя их я получаю объект у которого надо вызвать `->get()` что бы получить данные и не могу пользоваться подсказками IDE, она просто не знает с каким объектом происходит работа (тип возвращаемого значения у функции приходится удалять). При этом ничто не мешает сделать отдельный метод где-нибудь в сервисах что бы пользоваться блоками `->where` для всех таких "связей" с возможностью внедрения своей логики.

Вопрос: какой вариант предпочтительнее и почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hasOne, hasMany и пр. упрощает работу с отношениями, когда твоя таблица связана с другими таблицами.
Например как описано в документации, у тебя есть таблица статей, статьи могут содержать комментарии, и если ты следишь за нормализацией базы данных, а не пихаешь все в одну таблицу, то у тебя будет две таблицы со связью по внешнему ключу.
И чтобы не писать join для получения данных со связанной таблицы, ты можешь определить одно из отношений и потом получать данные таким образом:

```
Post:with('comments')->get()
```

Все статьи и комментарии к ним в одну строку.
Или например ты хочешь получить все комментарии для первой статьи

```
Post::find(1)->comments();
```

Но по сути тебя никто не заставляет этим пользоваться, это как одна из фишек Eloquent ORM для упрощения работы запросами.